# WiFi problem after 14.04 install

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I  did a clean Ubuntu 14.04.5 lts install and did all the updates. My computer is older Compaq desktop with a Netgear wireless  card. After booting I have  no wireless, the ethernet works

This is what I get

```
broadcom is enabled 02:02.0 Network controller 
[0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4321 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4329] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Netgear WN311B RangeMax Next 270 Mbps Wireless PCI Adapter [1385:7d00]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 64
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 11
    Region 0: Memory at fdcf8000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]

02:03.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8100/8101L/8139 PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter [10ec:8139] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2a24]
```

I need help but I am no computer wiz so go easy on me

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the Network Manager service by the following command works sometimes:

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
```

For 14.04 you can use:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: I tried this but gives me sudo: systemctl: command not found

Comment: Check the edit for Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: sudo: NetworkManager.service: command not found

Comment: @Terry check the edit I have made just now

Comment: that command ran thru thanks  but I still have no wifi mentioned in the network area at all .only shows wired connectin